# Save results of a select clause in a query to reuse in the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a query that shows the count of columns that are equal to a particular value, but only show the results where this count is exactly 2 (in Microsoft SQL Server).

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Menu.id,
       (
        select count(*)
        from (values (Menu.item1, Menu.item2, Menu.item3) as v(col)
        where v.col = 'banana'
       ) as numBananas
FROM Menu
WHERE (
       select count(*)
       from (values (Menu.item1, Menu.item2, Menu.item3) as v(col)
       where v.col = 'banana'
      ) = 2;
```

Is there a way I can avoid the redundant select count(*) statement in the SELECT clause and the WHERE clause?  I've tried the below, but it does not work:

```
SELECT Menu.id,
       (
        select count(*)
        from (values (Menu.item1, Menu.item2, Menu.item3) as v(col)
        where v.col = 'banana'
       ) as numBananas
FROM Menu
WHERE
    numBananas = 2;
```

Comment: what if the count is not equal to 2 ? what do you want as result ?

Comment: @Squirrel if the count is not 2, then don't include that row.  So numBananas should = 2 for every row.

Comment: do you have any sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an extra query level to make use of any sub-query results e.g.

Also I have corrected a syntax error at `as v(col)`

```
select id, NumBananas
from (
  select Menu.id, (
      select count(*)
      from (values (Menu.item1), (Menu.item2), (Menu.item3)) as v(col)
      where v.col = 'banana'
    ) NumBananas
  from Menu
) X
where X.NumBananas = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Beside using a derived table / outer query as Dale as shown, you can also use `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT  Menu.id, numBananas
FROM    Menu
CROSS APPLY
(
    select  count(*)
    from (
        values (Menu.item1), (Menu.item2), (Menu.item3)
    ) as v(col)
    where v.col = 'banana'
) bananacount (numBananas)
where numBananas    = 2
```

By the way, your original query `v(col)` is not correct. I guess it should be like this

```
from (
    values (Menu.item1), (Menu.item2), (Menu.item3)
) as v(col)
```

Or if you prefer a `CTE` approach

```
; with cte as
(
    SELECT  Menu.id,
        (
            select  count(*)
            from (
                values (Menu.item1), (Menu.item2), (Menu.item3)
            ) as v(col)
            where   v.col = 'banana'
        ) as numBananas
    FROM    Menu
) 
select  *
from    cte
WHERE   numBananas = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why unpivot?  Just do:

```
select m.*
from menu m
where ((case when m.item1 = 'banana' then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when m.item2 = 'banana' then 1 else 0 end) +
       (case when m.item3 = 'banana' then 1 else 0 end)
      ) = 2;
```

If you are going to unpivot, you can use a subquery:

```
select m.*
from menu m cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from (values (m.item1), (m.item2), (m.item3)) v(item)
      where item = 'banana'
     ) x
where cnt = 2;
```